# Problema respuesta AJAX con Symfony2 (PHP)

Tags: php, jquery, symfony2, twig

Tengo un problema con el código:

```
$cadenaScroll_respuesta.="<li> <div id='usuario-respond'><div id='imagen-usuario-respond' ><ul> <li id='nombreUsuario'> <b>".$respuesta->getUsuario()." </b></li><li id='avatar'> <img src = {{ asset('bundles/UsuarioBundle/Uploads/' ~ ".$respuesta->getFoto()." ~' ) }}'  width='100%'  height='100%'/> </li> <li id='opciones'><b>  opciones </b> </li> </ul></div>".$respuesta->getTexto()."</div></li>";
    }
```

la cadena anterior la devuelvo con un respond desde el controlador, y básicamente la necesito para al hacer el append del li a un ul (son temas de foros que se actualiza por scrolling a petición Ajax).

en mi función de success de jquery

```
success: function(data) {

                    alert(data);
                    $('#loading').hide();
                    //window.scrollTo(50, 0);
                    $('#detalle ul').append(data);
                },
```

en el navegador no me reconoce la dir de Asset (cuando le doy inspeccionar elemento me aparece)

```
<img src="{{" asset('bundles="" usuariobundle="" uploads="" '="" ~="" 1.jpg="" ~'="" )="" }}'="" width="100%" height="100%">
```

con lo cual intuyo que no me reconoce los simbolos / y me pone comillas demás

Comment: ¿Puedes poner el código que utilizas en la respuesta del controlador? Si estás utilizando new Response(); el trozo de Twig que metes dentro no se va a ejecutar, por eso tienes ese resultado.

Comment: Ponle las comillas al atributo src de la img.

Answer (score 1):

Es como te explican anteriormente, en tu controlador deberás tener como respuesta, digamos:

```
return $this->render('UsuarioBundle:Usuario:respuesta.html.twig', array('respuesta'=>$respuesta));
```

y el fragmento `respuesta.html.twig` contendrá tu código sustituyendo la variable php `$respuesta` por la variable twig correspondiente.

Answer (score 0):

Estas usando código twig dentro de un string en php pero para que se ejecute el interprete de twig debes usar el método "render" del controlador y tener el código twig en una vista.

No es tarea de jquery traducir dichos bloques y funciones. Debe llegarle exactamente el html que quieres que añada a la página.